# AutoMapper - mapping individual ints to an array

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 12 integers representing 12 months in an old database, and I need to map them to an array/list. The problem is I'm not sure how I can initialize the array in the model to size 12, in order to map it.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Model:

```
public class Year 
{
    public int[] Months { get; set; }   //How do I initialize to 12?
}
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<DataRow, Year>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Months[0], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["Jan"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Months[1], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["Feb"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Months[2], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src["Mar"]))
```

I've searched everywhere for pre-initialized arrays in models, but couldn't find anything on the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
public class Year
{
    public int[] Months { get; } = new int[12];
}
```

I also suggest to remove setter, make it as read only property - does not change ability to set individual items in array itself.